# Generate image snapshots using Docker with Playwright

Tags: javascript, docker, playwright

Locally, I can do the following:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('should work', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`https://playwright.dev`);
  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('test.png');
});
```

```sh
npx playwright test --update-snapshots
```

This works fine, but I want to generate the files via Docker so they're the same as when they run in CI. On the docs, the command is:

```sh
docker run --rm --network host -v $(pwd):/work/ -w /work/ -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.12.3-focal /bin/bash
npm install
npx playwright test --update-snapshots
```

This fails, just showing a red test. The docs don't mention much more than this, what is the solution here? I'm on an M1 Mac if it makes a difference.

```sh
    browserContext.newPage: Browser closed.
    ==================== Browser output: ====================
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] Crash keys:
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-7" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-6" = "--change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-5" = "--user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-4" = "--enable-crash-reporter=,"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-3" = "--crashpad-handler-pid=605"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-2" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-1" = "--no-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-switches" = "8"
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] Received signal 6
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006b75a71 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400e1f43c0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400ef3818b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400ef17859 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x004006b74d05 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x004006af433f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e1986f0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 000000400f0b2780
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 00002448000ec500 r13: 000000400e198950 r14: 00002448000ec510 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e1986f0  bp: 000000400e198940  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e1986f0
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    [pid=600][err] <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e198710 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 000000400f0b2780
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 0000109000184500 r13: 000000400e198970 r14: 0000109000184510 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e198710  bp: 000000400e198960  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e198710
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    [pid=600][err] [600:626:1118/015549.682667:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(326)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)
    [pid=600][err] [600:600:1118/015549.767331:FATAL:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Check failed: x11::Connection::Get()->Ready(). Missing X server or $DISPLAY
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006af3f10 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x004003d7ba29 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x004003d19067 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x00400824b507 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x00400824b49a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x00400471509f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004004715a4d <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x004004711dfb <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d692 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667d157 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #17 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] Crash keys:
    [pid=600][err]   "io_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x40044F7FE4 0x0"
    [pid=600][err]   "variations" = "19ebe09a-720b026c,23a898eb-fc93cf74,5f2c0f7c-3f4a17df,e4a357e9-3f4a17df,"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-experiments" = "4"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-30" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-29" = "--no-startup-window"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-28" = "--remote-debugging-pipe"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-27" = "--user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-26" = "--no-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-25" = "--no-service-autorun"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-24" = "--use-mock-keychain"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-23" = "--password-store=basic"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-22" = "--enable-automation"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-21" = "--no-first-run"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-20" = "--metrics-recording-only"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-19" = "--force-color-profile=srgb"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-18" = "--disable-sync"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-17" = "--disable-renderer-backgrounding"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-16" = "--disable-prompt-on-repost"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-15" = "--disable-popup-blocking"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-14" = "--disable-ipc-flooding-protection"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-13" = "--disable-hang-monitor"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-12" = "--allow-pre-commit-input"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-11" = "--disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,Globa"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-10" = "--disable-extensions"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-9" = "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-8" = "--disable-default-apps"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-7" = "--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-6" = "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-5" = "--disable-breakpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-4" = "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-3" = "--disable-background-timer-throttling"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-2" = "--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-1" = "--disable-background-networking"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-switches" = "30"
    [pid=600][err]   "osarch" = "x86_64"
    [pid=600][err]   "pid" = "600"
    [pid=600][err]   "ptype" = "browser"
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015550.409146:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Function not implemented (38)
    [pid=600][err] Received signal 6
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006b75a71 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400e1f43c0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400ef3818b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400ef17859 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x004006b74d05 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x004006af433f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004003d7ba29 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x004003d19067 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400824b507 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400824b49a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400471509f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x004004715a4d <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x004004711dfb <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400667d692 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #17 0x00400667d157 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #18 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #19 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #20 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #21 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #22 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e198310 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 000025e0000dd400 r13: 000000400e198570 r14: 000025e0000dd410 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e198310  bp: 000000400e198560  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e198310
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    =========================== logs ===========================
    <launching> /ms-playwright/chromium-930007/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
    <launched> pid=600
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015547.764472:ERROR:stack_trace_posix.cc(704)] Failed to parse the contents of /proc/self/maps
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015548.307639:ERROR:stack_trace_posix.cc(704)] Failed to parse the contents of /proc/self/maps
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015548.307646:ERROR:stack_trace_posix.cc(704)] Failed to parse the contents of /proc/self/maps
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015548.494378:FATAL:nacl_helper_linux.cc(435)] Check failed: nacl_sandbox->IsSingleThreaded(). 
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004000240779 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x00400020c063 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x00400020e6d0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400020f21e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400017fd6a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x004001e3e0b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x00400017f9ea <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    [pid=600][err] [618:618:1118/015548.584016:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(329)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
    [pid=600][err] [615:615:1118/015548.358993:FATAL:zygote_main_linux.cc(161)] Check failed: sandbox::ThreadHelpers::IsSingleThreaded(). 
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006af3f10 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] Crash keys:
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-8" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-7" = "--change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-6" = "--user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-5" = "--enable-crash-reporter=,"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-4" = "--crashpad-handler-pid=605"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-3" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-2" = "--no-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-1" = "--no-zygote-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-switches" = "9"
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] Received signal 6
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006b75a71 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400e1f43c0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400ef3818b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400ef17859 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x004006b74d05 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x004006af433f [618:618:1118/015548.587728:FATAL:zygote_main_linux.cc(161)] Check failed: sandbox::ThreadHelpers::IsSingleThreaded(). 
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006af3f10 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] Crash keys:
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-7" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-6" = "--change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-5" = "--user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-4" = "--enable-crash-reporter=,"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-3" = "--crashpad-handler-pid=605"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-2" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-1" = "--no-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-switches" = "8"
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] Received signal 6
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006b75a71 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400e1f43c0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400ef3818b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400ef17859 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x004006b74d05 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x004006af433f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004006680c57 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x00400667b7ae <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e1986f0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 000000400f0b2780
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 00002448000ec500 r13: 000000400e198950 r14: 00002448000ec510 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e1986f0  bp: 000000400e198940  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e1986f0
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    [pid=600][err] <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d16b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e198710 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 000000400f0b2780
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 0000109000184500 r13: 000000400e198970 r14: 0000109000184510 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e198710  bp: 000000400e198960  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e198710
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    [pid=600][err] [600:626:1118/015549.682667:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(326)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)
    [pid=600][err] [600:600:1118/015549.767331:FATAL:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Check failed: x11::Connection::Get()->Ready(). Missing X server or $DISPLAY
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006af3f10 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x004003d7ba29 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x004003d19067 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x00400824b507 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x00400824b49a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x00400471509f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004004715a4d <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x004004711dfb <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400667d692 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400667d157 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #17 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] Crash keys:
    [pid=600][err]   "io_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x40044F7FE4 0x0"
    [pid=600][err]   "variations" = "19ebe09a-720b026c,23a898eb-fc93cf74,5f2c0f7c-3f4a17df,e4a357e9-3f4a17df,"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-experiments" = "4"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-30" = "--enable-crashpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-29" = "--no-startup-window"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-28" = "--remote-debugging-pipe"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-27" = "--user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-Dveenw"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-26" = "--no-sandbox"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-25" = "--no-service-autorun"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-24" = "--use-mock-keychain"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-23" = "--password-store=basic"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-22" = "--enable-automation"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-21" = "--no-first-run"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-20" = "--metrics-recording-only"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-19" = "--force-color-profile=srgb"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-18" = "--disable-sync"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-17" = "--disable-renderer-backgrounding"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-16" = "--disable-prompt-on-repost"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-15" = "--disable-popup-blocking"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-14" = "--disable-ipc-flooding-protection"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-13" = "--disable-hang-monitor"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-12" = "--allow-pre-commit-input"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-11" = "--disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,Globa"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-10" = "--disable-extensions"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-9" = "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-8" = "--disable-default-apps"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-7" = "--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-6" = "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-5" = "--disable-breakpad"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-4" = "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-3" = "--disable-background-timer-throttling"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-2" = "--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess"
    [pid=600][err]   "switch-1" = "--disable-background-networking"
    [pid=600][err]   "num-switches" = "30"
    [pid=600][err]   "osarch" = "x86_64"
    [pid=600][err]   "pid" = "600"
    [pid=600][err]   "ptype" = "browser"
    [pid=600][err] 
    [pid=600][err] [1118/015550.409146:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Function not implemented (38)
    [pid=600][err] Received signal 6
    [pid=600][err] #0 0x004006b75f99 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #1 0x004006ae0513 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #2 0x004006b75a71 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #3 0x00400e1f43c0 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #4 0x00400ef3818b <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #5 0x00400ef17859 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #6 0x004006b74d05 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #7 0x004006af433f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #8 0x004006af4a5e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #9 0x004003d7ba29 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #10 0x004003d19067 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #11 0x00400824b507 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #12 0x00400824b49a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #13 0x00400471509f <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #14 0x004004715a4d <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #15 0x004004711dfb <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #16 0x00400667d692 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #17 0x00400667d157 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #18 0x00400667a9c5 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #19 0x00400667b49e <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #20 0x00400343b226 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #21 0x00400ef190b3 <unknown>
    [pid=600][err] #22 0x00400343b02a <unknown>
    [pid=600][err]   r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 000000400e198310 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  r12: 000025e0000dd400 r13: 000000400e198570 r14: 000025e0000dd410 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    [pid=600][err]   di: 0000000000000002  si: 000000400e198310  bp: 000000400e198560  bx: 000000401027f900
    [pid=600][err]   dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000000000000027  sp: 000000400e198310
    [pid=600][err]   ip: 000000400ef3818b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err]  trp: ffffffffffffffff msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
    [pid=600][err] [end of stack trace]
    [pid=600][err] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
    ============================================================
```

Comment: The docker environment do not have a window. In the github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2728#issuecomment-678083619 they recommend to run the script using xvfb-run --auto-servernum

Comment: xvfb-run is only needed if you want to run 'headful' tests in Docker. I think the author of the question isn't looking for that. snapshots should also work in a headless browser, just like screenshots and traces do.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions/questions:

- Have you tried a more recent version of Playwright? Playwright is moving quite fast, and from that perspective v1.12.3 is a bit old. (v1.16.3 is latest at the time of writing.)
- Is there any more browser output?
- Maybe with setting an environment variable for [verbose API logs](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug/#verbose-api-logs), you can get more details of what is going wrong.

Comment: Upgraded to newest version and same error. I added all the output to the original post, which is really long

Comment: @atomiks, I noticed this line:
 
` [pid=600][err] [600:600:1118/015549.767331:FATAL:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Check failed: x11::Connection::Get()->Ready(). Missing X server or $DISPLAY`


How does your playwright.config.js look? Did you enable headless? If not, that might be the problem. If you want to run headful tests, look at Honsa Stunna's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Update playwright version to > 16 works for me (with m1)

Answer (score -1):

Tried on Mac with intel chip:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.16.2-focal /bin/bash
```

Worked for me. Believe it helps

Comment: Only running this docker would fix it?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running your project via docker-compose? You can always attach your local files (e.g. your screenshots, test battery, etc) via volumes. Therefore you'll have the same files both locally and into your Docker application.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31035186)